# Change orientation of Subview of Application Window

Tags: iphone, ios

i try to make an help view which should be able to be shown Modal on Top of all from everywhere in the App, so i thought onShow my help view gets the Application `UIWindow` and adds itself to it as an Subview. And onClose the help view removes itself as an subview from the Application `UIWindow`.

Everything works quite well, except if the user changes the orientation of the device. Is there any possibility to get the System to change the orientation of my `UIView`? I already tried to redraw my View on

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)oldStatusBarOrientation
```

but unfortunately everything is rendered in the original orientation. It's like my is still in an different coordinate system.

Any suggestion would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use `presentModalViewController:animated:` to present the controller? Everything should then work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Usually the ModalViewController is called and dismissed by the Calling ViewController. Thought of an concept more like a Messagebox behaves. Callable everywhere even without knowing my parentViewController, plus Init, fire show and done.